# GridView column freeze to export xls

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5

In my web project I download an xls file.
I generate a gridview with the data I need and download.
Once I open the excel, I need a column to be blocked.

My code is as follows:

```
private DataTable tableExcel;    
public ActionResult returnExcel(HttpResponseBase response, string name)
{                       
    var grid = new GridView();
    grid.DataSource = tableExcel;
    grid.DataBind();            

    GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

    TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();                    
    HeaderCell = new TableCell();
    HeaderCell.Text = h.text;
    HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = colunesSpan;
    HeaderCell.Font.Bold = h.negreta;
    HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = h.aliniacio;
    HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
    HeaderGrid.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

    response.ClearContent();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename={name}.xls");
    response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);            

    grid.RenderControl(htw);            

    response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
}
```

The code works correctly, the only thing I need is to be able to implement the option to block or freeze a column.

```
grid.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
grid.Rows[0].CssClass = "locked";
```

I found these solutions but they do not work for GridView.

Comment: Please list the solutions you have already tried and explain why they don't work. Nobody wants to propose solutions that you have already tried.

Comment: Finally install the Spire.XLS for .NET package.
A very complete library that allows you to do what you want with a spreadsheet.